# PyQt4: set a default font?

Tags: fonts, pyqt

I'm adjusting a GUI written in PyQt4, and I'd like to change every last bit of text that appears in it to a different font than what PyQt uses by default. I've been doing this by calling

```
widget.setStyleSheet("font-family: DesiredFont;")
```

on every widget with text in it. This is very cumbersome.

Is there a way to tell PyQt to change the font that it defaults to?

Comment: Neither Qt nor PyQt sets a default font: It's taken from the system settings. Overriding the user's fonts is very poor design, but if you must do it, use [QApplication.setFont](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#setFont).

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks for that - if you'd like to get credit for it, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither Qt nor PyQt sets a default font: It's taken from the system settings. Overriding the user's fonts is very poor design, but if you must do it, use [QApplication.setFont](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#setFont).

Comment: Funny that this question just got its 2500th view, did not expect that!